# Date formatting issues when opening CSV

Tags: excel, csv, date, datetime

I have a CSV report that contains a date/time field, but when I open it in Excel, it seems to try and auto format the date and time, but has some issues with certain dates.

If I open the CSV file in Notepad, all of the dates follow the same format, which is something like `2/1/17 12:00 AM` (M/D/Y). However I get 2 different results, depending on the date. If the day is less than `12`, it will display in yyyy-MM-dd (for example: `2002-01-17  12:00:00 AM`), which is my system date format. If the day is > 12, it will display as `10/31/16 12:00 AM`, which is exactly how it is formatted in the CSV source. So, in those cases it looks like it is being treated as text.

If I change my short date format to M/d/y, then everything works fine, however I believe we have standardized on yyyy-MM-dd, and this will need to be used by multiple people, so changing the date format for any users who need to use this spreadsheet isn't a great option.

Ideally, what I would like to do is prevent this from happening altogether, if possible by not having the dates be automatically formatted when the document is opened. Is that possible?

Comment: That is due to you local settings,  These dates are in mm/dd/yyyy format and your local settings are reversed dd/mm/yyy  So the CSV 4/5/2017 is April 5th and your excel reads it as May 4th.  And since there are not more than 12 months it sees them as text as it cannot make the conversion.

Comment: Thanks. That is kind of what I figured. Is there a way to circumvent this by not having Excel convert the dates?

Comment: This is a common problem with many solutions posted here. You import the file instead of Opening it:  `Data►Get External Data►From Text`  This will open the `Text Import Wizard` and allow you to select the proper format for the data being imported.  You will need to split the time to a separate column

Comment: If you don't want the dates formatted at all, you can use the `Import` method I outlined above, and designate the column as `Text`

Comment: @RyanL have you find any programmatic solution for this

Comment: @vbhosale Unfortunately, no. If I remember correctly, I don't believe that I ever did any further work on this issue.